# Trigger SQL Server insert record and update a field from another table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have two tables:
tblProducts
-Id int,
-nameProduct varchar(10),
-Quantity int

tblSales
-Id
-Idproduct
-Quantity int

The Products table is related to the table 'Sales'. What I want to do is that when the sale of a product is added, the field 'quantity'  of the table 'Products'  is updated. In other words, decrease the number of products in the table 'Products' once a sale has been made.

I am trying to do it in the following way:

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_quantity
on Sales
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
UPDATE Products set Quantity=Quantity - inserted.Quantity WHERE 
Sales.id= inserted.id;
END
GO
```

Comment: What is your question here? You haven't asked one.

Comment: Do you also have records that relate to incoming inventory? If so, you really ought to consider some form of indexed view to maintain the quantities *automatically* for you rather than manually tracking and updating it. Manually tracking this information just *introduces* the opportunity for it to not be consistent with other data.

Comment: Also, you have no `FROM` clause in your `UPDATE` statement, so `inserted` and `Sales` can't be referenced. I also can't see any link in your statement between Products and `Sales` or `inserted`.

Answer (score 0):

Boy talk about sparse on details. I am guessing you are trying to do something like this. I would suggest that you don't use "id" as a column name. It is awful when a column name changes from table to table. If something is a ProductID, it is always a ProductID, not just an ID. Not really sure why you have quantity in both sales and product. Perhaps that is meaning QuantityOnHand in the Product table?

```
update p
set Quantity = Quantity - i.Quantity
from Products p
join inserted i on i.id = p.productid
```

--EDIT--

Here is one approach to ensuring this is safe from multiple row operations for the same ProductID.

```
update p
set Quantity = Quantity - x.NewQuantity
from Products p
cross apply 
(
    select NewQuantity = sum(i.Quantity) 
    from inserted i 
    where i.id = p.productid
) x
```

Comment: Danger! If multiple rows for a single product are inserted in a single statement, this update will only guarantee to apply an update relating to *one* of those rows. (This is the general danger of the `UPDATE ... FROM` syntax - it doesn't indicate that a row in the target table has been matched by multiple rows via the joins). We now have exactly the sort of inconsistency I warned about in the comments due to *manually* maintaining this total value.

Comment: Yes. This type of manual maintenance is generally a bad idea because there are some many possible issues. Would be better to calculate quantity available by taking the sum of received goods - sum of sold goods.

Comment: You could at least make your example *safe* for multi-row inserts by pushing `inserted` into a subquery that `GROUP`s based on `ProductID`s

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever not sure what you mean there. Wouldn't sum(i.Quantity) work?

Comment: Yes, but in order to be able to *write* that `SUM` expression, you need to introduce a subquery with a `GROUP BY` clause.